# Rails structure for static and user specific models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, mongodb, models

Our application needs a section where users can answer questions in a prompt. Unfortunately, we cannot think of a way to structure this where it still seems railsy and looks okay in the database (mongodb).

Here is our model structure: 
http://hastebin.com/axumavitob.model

```
Model: TrainingLevel (this is the overarching model, like certification level)
  String name
  has_many :sections

Model: Section
  has_many :prompts
  Integer type

Model: prompt
  String wavFile
  ResponseMatrix rmatrix

Model: ResponseMatrix
  has_many :responses, as: :correct_reponses
  has_many :responses, as: :acceptable_responses

Model: Response seeded in database
  String response text
  String wavfile
```

Essentially we need a way to have the questions pre seeded in the database, but be able to keep track of each users progress for a section. Where should we save the data? Saving multiple prompts and having a template prompt in the same collection seems unnatural, and yet saving each users progress in a different collection also seems redundant. We've considered embedded documents, but how would we do this?

Thanks!